# Secure XML parsing with Jaxb2Marshaller

Tags: java, xml, unmarshalling, jaxb2

I need to implement xml parsing that will prevent XXE and Entity Expansion attack. Seems that this is a code that will manage both issues:

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyClass.class);
XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
xif.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_SUPPORTING_EXTERNAL_ENTITIES, false);
xif.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.SUPPORT_DTD, false);
xif.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_REPLACING_ENTITY_REFERENCES, false);
XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(new StringSource(body));
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
MyClass myObject = (MyClass) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xsr);
```

By I'd want to do the same with Jaxb2Marshaller. This unmarshaller is already used across the project and I'm able to get it thought @Autowire annotation. Also classesToBeBound is already set in applicationContext.xml so I do not need to create JAXBContext for each action.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Some parsers these days default to preventing Entity Expansion attacks, by limiting the number of entities permitted. (Xerces does, for example.)

Comment: Seems that this is not my case. Also I read that this is not 100% true. http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/03/preventing-entity-expansion-attacks-in.html (one of the comments). Any way I still need to prevent XXE

Comment: a marshaller does not parse xml, it generates it.  only an unmarshaller parses xml.